# Issue in htaccess redirecting from http to https

Tags: .htaccess

I went the entire website to be accesed only with https.

In `.htaccess` to i written the following rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-website.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my-website.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But it causes "This webpage has a redirect loop" 
Anyone can guide me a fix for this.

Comment: Using [mod_rewrite is not recommended for your use case](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL). But id you really have to you can try [this example](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS).

Answer (score 0):

Normally with a single site, you can use that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.my-website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```